# Magento 2 : Error while Compilation

Tags: magento2, upgrade, compilation

we are facing this issue while we are updating our portal from 2.3.4. to 2.4.6.

Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/9 [===============>------------]  55% 30 secs 370.0 MiB
In ClassReader.php line 57:

Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #21 [  Magento\InventoryApi\Api\GetSourceItemsBySkuInterface $sourceItemsBySku ] of Mageplaza\Seo\Plugin\SeoRender class

In GetParameterClassTrait.php line 34:

Class "Magento\InventoryApi\Api\GetSourceItemsBySkuInterface" does not exist

setup:di:compile

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? We are updating all plugins and the magento is already on 2.4.6. p4

Comment: you probably are just missing to update the Mageplazza module to a comptabible version with m246. Either that, either you miss a proper composer install to get the missing file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this steps.

1. Either Disable `Mageplaza\Seo` plugin from the website OR update the extension version which compitible with Magento 2.4.6.
2. Then run the following commands from the CLI.

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
   ```
3. Then run the compilation command again from the `CLI`.